# saving a csv to txt only one column data

Tags: csv, export-to-text

Hey guys so i have this data in csv(fifty csv):

```
income,output
1000,2000
2000,1000
1000,2000
3000,4000
4000,3000
5000,5000
```

i would like to combine and save the first column from fifty csv to one txt

so the output will be like this:

```
1000
2000
1000
3000
4000
5000
so on and so forth
```

how would i do that ?

Comment: is this a python question...are you intending to do this once...or as a repeatable action as part of a program?

Comment: Add more details: there are plenty of ways to do that. You want to do it for an only file with an ide or a text editor? You want to do it using bash? batch? Programmaticaly from python, C#, javascript,...?

Comment: We need more details.  Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.